# Having an ejs issue with a button

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm having an issue with ejs in a button. I want the text of the button to change when you click it just like a follow/unfollow button.

```
 <% if (user.profile._id.toString() !== profile._id.toString()) { %>
                                                      <% if (!profile.likedUsers.includes(user.profile._id)) { %>
                                                        <form action="/date/<%= profile._id %>/likedProfile" method="POST">
                                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mw-75">Rub Beaks with <%= profile.name %></button>
                                                        </form>
                                                      <% } else { %>
                                                      <form action="/date/<%= profile._id %>/likedProfile" method="POST">
                                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger mw-75">Break <%= profile.name %>'s Heart</button>
                                                      </form>
                                                      <% } %> 
                                                    <% } %>
```

Comment: Is it enough to change the text on the button or do you need to send any data back to server also?

Answer (score 0):

EJS can't change values after it is rendered. It doesn't work like states in react or something like that. The way it is now in yout code, will be one of both forms. EJS won't save any information of the unsatisfacted condition.

The way you can do only using EJS is send a request to server and re-render all the page with the new content, but it doesn't seems to be a good way.

The easiest way is using JS to change the form content with an onclick handler.